# ASP.NET DropdownList inside a ListView

Tags: asp.net

I currently have a ListView for entering credit card details (you can enter more than one credit card):

```
 <asp:ListView ID="CreditCardListView" class="block" SortExpression="DataType" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" runat="server">

                    <ItemTemplate  >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="CreditCardNumber" runat="server" class="inline" Text='<%# Eval("AuthorName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="VerificationCode" runat="server" class="inline" Text='<%# Eval("AuthorName1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DdlMonth" class="inline"  Width="50px"  Font-Names="Andalus" CssClass="ddl input-header" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="1"  Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="2"  Value="2"></asp:ListItem>

                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                </tr>

                            </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

The cuestion is, is there any way to set the DropDownList (DdlMonth) in the code behind?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `DropDownList` databound? You can access the list in `CreditCardListView_ItemDataBound` handler.

Comment: Thanks @AlexKudryashev, by adding a handler `OnItemDataBound="CreditCardListView_ItemDataBound"` I'm able to edit it!